# What is the distribution of the initial point of a stationary VAR(1) process?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, autoregressive

I want to generalize the answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357272/the-distribution-of-the-initial-point-of-an-ar-process) to this case of a VAR(1) model. Suppose that $X_t \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and that $\Lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

> If we have the stochastic process $\left\{ X_t, t = 1, 2, \ldots \right\}$ following the model 
>   $$X_t = \Lambda X_{t-1} + e_t \quad \text{ where } e_t \sim \mathcal N (0, \Sigma)$$
>   what is the distribution of the inital point $X_1$?

Using the idea proposed in the linked question, suppose that $B = \mathbb V (X_t) = \mathbb V (X_{t-1})$. Then, 
\begin{align}
B &= \mathbb V (\Lambda X_{t-1} + e_t) \\
&= \Lambda B \Lambda^{\top} + \Sigma.
\end{align}

---

For a simple example, let $n = 2$, $\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_1^2 & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma_2^2 \end{bmatrix}$, $\Lambda = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 \end{bmatrix}$, and $B = \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ z & w \end{bmatrix}$, where the free elements are non-zero.

Subsituting these in to the "fixed point" equation yields
$$\begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ z & w \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 
\lambda_1^2 x + \sigma_1^2 & \lambda_1 \lambda_2 y \\ \lambda_1 \lambda_2 z & \lambda_2^2 w + \sigma_2^2 \end{bmatrix}$$
which implies that $$x = \frac{\sigma_1^2}{1 - \lambda_1^2} \quad y = \frac{\sigma_2^2}{1 - \lambda_2^2}$$
and $y = z = 0$.

So in this case the starting distribution would be $X_1 \sim \mathcal{N} \left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\sigma_1^2}{1 - \lambda_1^2} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{\sigma_2^2}{1 - \lambda_2^2}\end{bmatrix} \right)$ provided $|\lambda_1| < 1$ and $|\lambda_2| <1$.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/251548/77222

Comment: @JarleTufto: Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For stationarity we require $\text{var} (X_2) = \text{var} (X_1) \equiv B$. This leads to the "fixed point" equation $$B = \Lambda B \Lambda^{\top} + \Sigma.$$ Using the work from @JarleTufto [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/251548/77222) the "fixed point" equation leads to:
\begin{align}
\text{vec} (B) &= \text{vec} (\Lambda B \Lambda^{\top} + \Sigma) \\
&= \text{vec} (\Lambda B \Lambda^{\top}) + \text{vec} (\Sigma) \\
&= (\Lambda \otimes\Lambda) \text{vec} (B) + \text{vec} (\Sigma)
\end{align}
 Then, $X_1 \sim \mathcal N \left(0, B\right)$ where $B$ is found from the following equation:
$$\text{vec} (B) = \left[ \text{Id} - (\Lambda \otimes \Lambda) \right]^{-1} \text{vec} (\Sigma).$$ 
If the inverse does not exist, then I believe that a psuedo-inverse will work just fine.

---

One nice thing I've noticed is that if $\Lambda$ and $\Sigma$ are both diagonal matrices, then the "fixed" point equation is fairly simple to solve.

$$B = \Lambda B \Lambda^{\top} + \Sigma$$ leads to $$B = \left( \text{Id} - \Lambda^2 \right)^{-1} \Sigma = \Sigma \left( \text{Id} - \Lambda^2 \right)^{-1}$$