# What does it mean for a Markov chain to have an invariant distribution but not be iid?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo

I am reading chapter 10 of the *Handbook of Markov Chain Monte Carlo* (Chapman and Hall/CRC, 2011), by James P. Hobert on the Data Augmentation algorithm, which honestly just looks like a Gibbs sampler to me.

In section 10.2.4 (page 268) on the Central Limit Theorem, they calculate the covariance between $X_1$ and $X_0$, assuming that $X_0$ is sampled from the invariant distribution $f_X$, which implied that $X_1$ is also sampled from $f_X$. If this is the case, shouldn't they both independent? In what sense are they both sampled from an invariant distribution if they're not independent samples?

Comment: Yes, data augmentation is a type of Gibbs sampler. While $X_t\sim f$ for all $t$'s when $X_0\sim f$, this does not imply they are iid from $f$. They are _marginally_ from $f$, not jointly (iid) from $f$

Comment: See as an illustration the [case of the AR(1) Markov chain](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/449341/7224).

Comment: Thanks Xi'an! I've been following you and your blog for a while. By this reasoning, the Markov Chain that produces $X_{t+1}=X_{t}$ would also satisfy this condition?

Comment: The constant Markov chain is the endless repetition of one single value, which is a realisation of the stationary distribution in the case it is generated that way.