# Is a stable VAR model geometrically ergodic

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-process, ergodic

If we have a VAR process:

$\begin{align} 
\mathbf{y}_t = A_1\mathbf{y}_{t-1} + \dots + A_d\mathbf{y}_{t-d} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}_t, \quad t \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align}$

With the stability condition met:

$\det(I - A_1z - \dots - A_d z^d) \neq 0$ for $|z| \leq 1$

Do we know that the process is then geometrically ergodic.

---

I know that from theorem 2.4(i) in [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-69395-8), we know that an AR($d$) process is geometrically ergodic, but I do not know if this generalises to VAR($d$) processes.

The book takes that theorem from Theorem 3.1 of [this paper](https://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A6n49.pdf) where the conditions are listed as (3.1) and (3.2) above.

---

To summarise, we know that a stable AR model is geometrically ergodic, I want to know if this holds for a VAR process.